# Azure AD - Populate Group Information in Claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to populate the Claims token with User Group Information that I will fetch from Graph API. This is be specifically useful to port an existing Windows auth application to Azure. All my IsInRole() functions will work as is. I tried following this post

[Populate Claims Information from Graph API](http://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2014/10/24/add-role-based-authorisation-based-on-azure-ad-group-membership/)

but unless I update the app manifest with groupMembershipClaims, I may not be able to populate the groups information. I am trying to avoid this since I am not a Global Admin on my corporate tenant. Is there any more sample codes that I can follow to do the same?

Comment: You should ask a global admin to update the manifest as part of a deployment step to production ...

Comment: In my experience, you don't need to be a global admin to update the app manifest with this change.

Comment: @ChrisGillum, No you will not be allowed to modify the manifest unless you are a global admin.

Comment: @Thomas, There are ways in which I am able to fetch the Group information from Graph API without updating the app manifest. However, I have to store it in a session variable or so and Override the IsInRole() method to make things work. I was thinking that as soon as the user is authenticated, the claims information should be filled with group information also. If I modify the app manifest, it will automatically populate the token with group information. But the token will be too heavy and will populate only 200 groups.

Comment: @Ashish, to get the groups added to the token you need to update the manisfest. otherwise as you said you can query the graph API to get this don. Is it not possible for you to ask to a global admin to update the manifest file ?